# how to use Run Keyword If with 2 conditions in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

Hi I am using the [Run Keyword If](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If) in the [builtin library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html), and I want to run a keyword if two conditions are satisfied.
with one condition I was doing it like this:

```
Scale Down Service Should Succeed
Get Services
:For    ${Service}      IN              @{BODY.json()}
    \   Run Keyword If      ${Service['DOWN']}     Scale Down Service With Correct ID And Can be Scaled Down   ${Service['ID']}     ${Service['ContainersRunning']}
```

now my question is how can I do this with 2 conditions for example ${Service['DOWN']} (type boolean) and ${Service['Name']}="service"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "AND" operator to verify two conditions as below:

```
Run Keyword If      ${Service['DOWN']} and ${Service['Name']}=="service"     Scale Down Service With Correct ID And Can be Scaled Down   ${Service['ID']}     ${Service['ContainersRunning']}
```